# Is it safe to delete from db orphaned posts i.e. whose post_parent no longer exists?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, database, maintenance

I inherited a couple of **WP + WooCommerce** shops with roughly 30,000 products for sale each, and a `wp_postmeta` which is over a million lines. The former webmasters ran away.

In an effort to clean up old stuff, I noticed a `post_parent` field in `wp_posts`, and queried the database for orphans:

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE NOT post_parent IN 
  (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts) AND post_parent>0
```

and found thousands of records.
All of these records have a `post_parent` which no longer exists.

Just out of curiosity, I checked `wp_postmeta`:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta where post_id in
  (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts where not post_parent in 
     (select ID from wp_posts) and post_parent>0 )
```

and found 60,000 records.

**Is it safe to delete them**, along with any references from the tables `wp_postmeta`, `wp_comments`, `wp_commentmeta`, `wp_term_relationships`, `wp_wc_product_meta_lookup` ?

Else, can you suggest a strategy to clean up the database from spurious data?